# JQuery form upload hang passing a model object in the data tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm using the jquery form uploader.  (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)
I need to pass data in my form as well as the file upload itself.  I do this (using typescript):

```
handleFormUpload(event) {
var successCallback: (data: any, textStatus: string, jqXhr: JQueryXHR) => void = this.handleResponse;
var options = {
   url: "file/upload",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   data: {
      "Name": this.model.get("Name"),
      "Index": this.model.get("Index"),
      "Type": model.get("Type")
       },
  }
```

This works fine.  However it seems odd that I can't just pass:

`data: this.model`

or something to that effect.  For some reason, when I do that and try to upload my file and send the form, it just hangs until Firefox tells me a script is taking a long time and I can stop it.  Is there a reason why I can't just pass the model and I have to create a model on the fly?  Thanks.

Edit:Added the surrounding function code per comment.  handleFormUpload gets called when a button is pressed, wired up in a marionette view.

Comment: We need to know what the context of `this` is? Is this within a function that is triggered by an event? You need to post all the code.

Comment: @Papa Sorry about that, I edited my code.  It's wrapped in a function that just gets called on a button press.

Comment: what is `model`? Are you using backbone?

Comment: @Papa Yes, just a backbone model that has those properties, Name, Index, Type